# Is Open vSwitch necessary for my setup?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, vmware-vsphere, openvswitch, vswitch

I've been considering moving my VMware-based dedicated server to Linux using KVM/QEMU. The only major hurdle remaining is networking. My current setup is:

```
NIC <---> Public vSwitch <--->  Router (IPFire) <---> Private vSwitch <---> VMs
```

The host has a public IP, as does the router VM.

My question is: **is Open vSwitch necessary to replicate this setup**, or would two standard Linux bridges suffice - e.g. `br0` for public and `br1` for VMs, and the router VM having a NIC attached to both?

Comment: I don't see any need for Open vSwitch here; you can easily replicate this setup without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple setup with two bridges, no need for OVS